# can you set a value for a row in a table?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I would like to set a row value for each of my rows (tr) that are generated from my database. so let's say I have the following table being generated:

```
while ($row = $database->fetch_array($result))
{
$i=1-$i;
$class = "row".$i;


echo "<tr class='{$class} productId' id='{$row['productId']}'>

<td > ". $row['category']."</td>
<td >" . $row['productNo']. "</td>
<td>" . $row['productName'].  "</td>
<td class='edit'>" . intval($row['quantity']).  "</td>
 <td>" . $row['sfLf'].  "</td>
<td>".  $row['cost']. "</td>
<td>".  $row['total']."</td>
  </tr>";
}
```

Here i have tried to pass the productId value through the id attribute but unfortunately the id stays the same for all rows when I  try retrieving in the following script:

```
$(".productId").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "populateInventory.php",
        data: "productId="+$(".productId").attr('id'),
        success: function(msg){
          $("#invHistoryTable").html(msg);
        }
    });
```

How do I go about to pass the right productId value to my php page using the above ajax command? 
thank you

Comment: even if I do the following I am not yet able to get the right result: data: { productId: $(".productId").attr('id') }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `post` method but you are sending a string. You should send a key/value pair, also `attr` returns ID of the first selected element in jQuery collection, not the element that has fired the event, you can use `this` keyword which refers to the clicked element.

```
$(".productId").click(function(event) {
    // event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "populateInventory.php",
        data: { productId: this.id } ,
        success: function(msg){
          $("#invHistoryTable").html(msg);
        }
    }); 
})
```